# IP Resolution of AD Domain, DFS and DNS/WINS lookup problem

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, dfs

**Short story** One day, on client computers, the remote DFS \\country1.company.com\company stopped working and \\country1.company.com keeps resolving to a local server IP. However, if the request is executed on the local server, the DFS resolves correctly (at least it seems). I have searched everywhere but cannot find what is wrong except a suspicious WINS entry on the remote DNS which looks like this:

```
Name: (same as parent folder)
Type: WINS Lookup
Data: [192.168.3.A][192.168.3.B]
```

where 192.168.3.X is our local subnet, and both the above address are our local Win2k3 and Win2k8 servers respectively.

Any advice where I can look please? Thank you.

**Long story** We have 2 physical office locations that are NOT in the same forest, but still configured such that they are in country1.company.com and country2.company.com. There is full trust in between. We are connected via MPLS VPN.

\\country1.company.com\company is a DFS namespace in the country1.company.com domain. In DNS of country2.company.com, country1.company.com is added as a secondary forward lookup zone.

country1.company.com is in the subnet 192.168.2.x while country2.company.com is in the subnet 192.168.3.x

**EDIT**: Not sure if it helps, we recently installed (halfway, still not operational) DFS on our local site with the namespace \\country2.company.com\company. The \\country1.company.com\company namespace is not specified in the DFS on our local site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a network trace while attempting to access the DFS path. http://blogs.technet.com/b/josebda/archive/2009/04/15/understanding-windows-server-2008-dfs-n-by-analyzing-network-traces.aspx might be useful to help decipher the data.

The WINS lookup entry is useful if you havent added all the records in a DNS domain but want to use WINS entries as qualifying records. Example zone is called domain.com with above wins lookup entry. You lookup server.domain.com but see no entry in the DNS zone itself for server.domain.com. But the WINS server you are pointing to in above WINS lookup has an entry called server with some a.b.c.d type IP address. Hence if you lookup server.domain.com, the DNS server will lookup WINS for an entry for server and return a DNS response to server.domain.com as a.b.c.d.

If WINS is resolving the name through WINS to an invalid IP address then and only then would I consider the WINS lookup to be bad.